# Blocking Task with Event Flags halts the program

Tags: c, stm32, freertos, cmsis

I'm integrating FreeRTOS cmsis_v2 on my STM32F303VCx and come to a certain problem then using Event Flags when blocking the task to wait for operation approval from another task.

If the task executes the following code, all other tasks get minimal runtime (understandably because OS is constantly checking evt_flg):

```
for(;;)
{       
    flag = osEventFlagsWait (evt_flg, EventOccured, osFlagsWaitAny, 0);
    if (flag == EventOccured)
    {
      /* Task main route */
      osEventFlagsClear (evt_flg,EventOccured);
    }
 }
```

But if to set timeout to `osWaitForver`:  `osEventFlagsWait (evt_flg, EventOccured, osFlagsWaitAny, osWaitForver )`, the whole program goes into HardFault.

What's the best solution for such behavior? I need the task to wait for a flag and don't block other ones, such as terminal input read, from running.

Comment: IMO it is because it cant switch the task. on stm32 platforms it usually indicates the interrupt priority problem or call to the not ISR functions in ISR

Comment: If the OS was constantly checking the event flag, there would be no point in having an event flag..

Comment: What do the other tasks do ? Do they set event flag in a loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task code the question provides is constantly busy, polling the RTOS event.
This is a design antipattern, it is virtually always better to have the task block until the event source has fired. The only exception where a call to `osEventFlagsWait()` with a zero timeout could make more sense is if you have to monitor several different event/data sources for which there is not a common RTOS API to wait for (and even then, this is only an "emergency exit"). Hence, `osWaitForver` shall be used.

Next, the reason for the HardFault should be sought. Alone in this task code, I don't see a reason for this - the HardFault source is likely somewhere else. When the area the HardFault can come from, that could be worth a new question (or already fixed). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, although a solution was found by reading "Little book of semaphores" and applying sync techniques described in the book.

Comment: Fine. What are those synch techniques like? Have you applied it to your firmware on top of CMSIS-RTOSv2 ?